# How many positive integers, not exceeding $100$, are multiples of $2$ or $3$ but not $4$?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many positive integers, not exceeding $100$, are multiples of $2$ or $3$ but not $4$?

I was thinking the principle of inclusion-exclusion would work for this.

$$ \frac{100}{2} + \frac{100}{3} - \frac{100}{6} - \frac{100}{8} - \frac{100}{12} + \frac{100}{24} $$

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have a problem with whether this is right, you can just count and check in less than ten minutes. Or choose a smaller number like $50$ or $25$ and see if it works for that.

Answer (score 2):

$ \lfloor \frac{100}{2} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{100}{3} \rfloor$ will have double counted those number that are divisible by $6$, so we need to subtract $\lfloor \frac{100}{6} \rfloor$. To remove those numbsers that are didvible by $4$ subtract $\lfloor \frac{100}{4} \rfloor$, thus we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lfloor \frac{100}{2} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{100}{3} \rfloor -\lfloor \frac{100}{6} \rfloor - \lfloor \frac{100}{4} \rfloor =50 +33 -16-25 = \color{red}{42}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You have a typographical error in your answer.  You wrote $\color{red}{+} \lfloor \frac{100}{4} \rfloor$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, a typo, corrected now ... thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have $100/2$ numbers divisible by $2$, $33$ numbers divisible by $3$. Out of those, $\lfloor{100/6}\rfloor=16$ are divisible by $6$, so are counted twice. There are $25$ numbers divisible by $4$. All of those are divisible by $2$, so they meet the first criteria. Answer is $50+33-16-25$

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Venn Diagrams to 'picture' the situation:

[image]

We are interested in the numbers that would be located in areas $V, VI,$ and $VII$. In fact, let's just treat these as variables for numbers, i.e. we are looking for the value of $V+VI+VII$

Using Inclusion-Exclusion kind of thinking, we see that we can get to $V+VI+VII$ by adding $Div_2 = II+IV+V+VI = 50$ and $Div_3 = III+IV+VI+VII=33$, then subtracting $Div_6 = IV + VI = 16$, then subtracting $Div_4 = I+II+II+IV=25$, and finally adding $I$ (but $I=0$, since anything divisible by $4$ is automatically divisible by $2$)

Thus: $V+VI+VII=50+33-16-25+0=42$

Answer (score 0):

Inclusion-exclusion is an *excellent* idea.

There are $\frac {100}{2}$ multiples of $2$ (if we don't count $0$).  There are $\lfloor \frac{100}3\rceil$ multiples of $3$.  But there are $[\frac{100}{\lcd{2*3}}]$ that are both multiples of $2$ and $3$.  But we wish to eliminate the multiples of $4$.  There are $[\frac {100} {\lcm(2,4)}]$ that are multiples of $2$ and $4$ and $[\frac{100}{\lcm {3,4}}]$ that are multiples of $3$ and $4$. And $[\frac{100}{\lm{3,4,2}}]$ that are multiples of all three.

So the answer is $(\frac {100}{2} +\lfloor \frac{100}3\rceil-[\frac{100}{\lcd{2*3}}])- ([\frac {100} {\lcm(2,4)}]+[\frac{100}{\lcm {3,4}}]-[\frac{100}{\lm{3,4,2}}])=$

$(50 + 33 - 16) - (25+8 - 8) = 42$

If you think this out logically though, you do the evens ($50$ of them), remove those divisible by $4$, ($25$ of the so the $25$ evens, $2,6,10,...,96$), add the multiples of $3$ ($33$ of them so $58$ so far).  Remove the multiples of $6$ ($16$ of them so that is $42$ so far).  We don't have to worry about the multiples of $3$ and $4$ as those were removed when we removed the multiples of $4$.  So... $42$.

Comment: I wanted to fix the occurrences of `\lcm` in this answer which are not rendered correctly. But then I noticed that there is also `\lcd` and `\lm`. Are they just typos and all of them are supposed to be lcm?